# jquery append in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm have a problem with jquery's append() function i chrome.

I'm working on a browser chat and are retrieving chat-messages with long-polling from the server.
When the client gets a new message, the message is appended to the specific chat instance div.

Immediately after the append, i want to scroll set the scrollTop, i.e "scroll to the bottom" of the chat_session_text.
This works fine in most browsers, but not in chrome. After some research, append() doesn't appear to be synchronous in chrome?

If i log the scrollHeight in my code it shows the wrong height for the div. BUT, if i paste this code in the chrome-console, it is the right height! So, i'm suspecting the DOM is not ready with the appended div.

Here is my code:

```
var strHtmlToAppend = $('<div class="chat_message"><img class="imgThumb2" style="float:left;" src="UserImage.aspx?alias=' + fromUserID + '" border="0" alt="">' + strMsg + '</div>');
$('#' + elm + ' .chat_session_text').append(strHtmlToAppend);
console.log($('#' + elm + ' .chat_session_text').prop("scrollHeight")); 
$('#' + elm + ' .chat_session_text').prop({ scrollTop: $('#' + elm + ' .chat_session_text')[0].scrollHeight });
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? maybe som kind of callback for the append() function once the DOM i ready?

Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dvirazulay/pD7pL/1/ - it works quite well in chrome. Could you provide a jsfiddle that shows how it is acting wrong in chrome?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `scrollHeight` is not too well supported on Chome (example. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=34224) and the claim that append() is asynchronous I've found unsupported. Maybe the fact that the console is open changes the behavior of the whole page (different height)?

I suggest you use jQuery-provided functions instead of accesseing the properties directly, http://api.jquery.com/height/ for the getter and http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/ for the setter.